# Overcome character limit in shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes

I have a series of shapefiles that I need to attach attribute data to, however, the text is quite long (up to 1000 characters including spaces).

I know there is no way to get around this using shapefile format, but is there a method by which I can turn my polygons into a different format where I can add up to 1000 characters of text into attribute fields?

Comment: Use GeoPackage, SQLite, or some other modern file format.

Comment: For Shapefiles this is not possible. Consider using the GeoPackage file format or another modern format.

Comment: High-five to @MrXsquared for highlighting the word "modern" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Refactor field and set field length of the text fields to 0 and save the output to geopackage:

[image]